# How to returning raw, untokenized version of an elastic search field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm issuing a query like the following:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "packages": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "array1"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "package_counts": {
          "terms": {
            "size": 10000,
            "field": "array1.innerArray.property"
          }
        }
      }
   }
  }
}
```

For property values that contain "-", ElasticSearch seems to tokenize the value and create a bucket for each portion.  (So "foo-bar" ends up counting in two buckets, "foo" and "bar.")

How can I get ElasticSearch to use the raw, untokenized version of the field, so that "foo-bar" is counted in only one bucket?

array1.innerArray.property.raw doesn't seem to work.

Relevant portion of my type mapping:

```
 "name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
```

Unfortunately I don't control these mappings.

Comment: If you don't control the mapping, you're out of luck. You need to be able to change the mapping to use either add `"index": "not_analyzed"` to the `name` field or add a non-analyzed sub-field to it.